# Automatically connect to MySQL master if slave not working in Symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, master-slave

I've set up a master-slave connection that works just fine. It seems to read from the slave and write to the master. For the MySQL part I used [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql). Any modifications done to the master are immediately applied to the slave as well. Both databases use the 5.6 version.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8

                slaves:
                    slave1:
                        host:     "%sdatabase_host%"
                        port:     "%sdatabase_port%"
                        dbname:   "%sdatabase_name%"
                        user:     "%sdatabase_user%"
                        password: "%sdatabase_password%"
```

However, if the slave's mysql server is down (or badly configured), wouldn't it make sense for the connection to be made to the master? In this case, the whole app crashes and I find that a bit annoying.

I'd like to know if there is a way to connect to the master if the slave is not working. Or please tell me if it's a bad practice.

I believe it has to do with [MasterSlaveConnection](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connections/MasterSlaveConnection.php) since that one seems to be used when slaves are configured for a dbal connection, otherwise [Connection](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php) is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most comfortable option would be (at this context) to set-up a HAProxy instance in front of MySQL-slave server. Then specify HAProxy as slave server in Symfony configuration. If proxy detects it's (slave) down, it will transparently pass-through whole connection to the master server.

See some examples how to setup HAProxy with behavior I described:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-mysql-load-balancing--3

Comment: `All your MySQL servers have to be configured to perform Master-Master replication as load balancing involves both reading and writing to all the backends.` I have a M-S case, though. And the purpose was indeed to read from slaves and write to master only, so this isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: I didn't say that it is an exact manual. Load balancer configuration is completely up to you. DO described M-M; I told you to introduce a separated load-balancer that will route the traffic accordingly to the environment status.

Comment: I see. I guess that could work, although my question is a bit more Symfony-related.

Comment: I'm afraid pure-Symfony solution may not be available - it's simple, indeed: it requires to check somehow host availiability. Without no access to lower ISO/OSI layers, checking availability may cause an unnecessary overhead.